# Find out which NodeJS is used by Playwright

Tags: node.js, playwright

I have apparently removed `nodejs` from my machine using this command:

```
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove nodejs && sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove npm
```

But Playwright still manages to work, so does it come with a built-in Node installation or something ? If yes, where can I get the path of its Node ?

Note that I'm using [Playwright for Go](https://github.com/playwright-community/playwright-go).

Comment: Have you tried running "node -v" or "which node"?

Comment: @sahmeepee the "node" command is not found because I uninstalled nodejs from my system

Comment: and the output of "top -c" or "ps ax" while it is running?